Is there an essential difference in using of `Widget` or `WidgetBuilder` to pass widget as parameter to another widget in flutter
Let's say I have a widget:
class MyWidget {
  final Widget? leading;
  final WidgetBuilder? trailing;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        if(leading != null ) leading,
        AnotherWidget(),
        if(trailing != null) trailing(context),
      ],
    );
}

I am curious is there any pros/cons to use WidgetBuilder instead Widget for trailing?

Until someone posts a real answer - I remember reading about this a while ago: WidgetBuilder will create a new context object; where in your example you are passing the same context used by MyWidget. A new context being created might be very important in some cases, in some cases will not matter.

Yes, there are several essential differences between using a Widget and WidgetBuilder in Flutter:

Construction Approach:

With a Widget, you pass an instance of a widget that is already built.
With a WidgetBuilder, you use a function that returns a widget, allowing deferred construction.


Context Handling:

Widgets passed directly typically use the context they're given during construction.
WidgetBuilders can create and use a new context, which is useful for accessing inherited widgets or when the context might change.


Rebuilding capability:

Widgets passed directly generally don't need rebuilding with a new context.
WidgetBuilders allow rebuilding the widget with a new context, which can be necessary for certain scenarios.


Use Cases:

Widgets are suitable when the widget's context is sufficient and doesn't need to change.
WidgetBuilders are suitable when the widget needs a new context or context-specific information that might change.


Simplicity:

Widgets are simpler and more straightforward to use.
WidgetBuilders are slightly more complex due to the function and context handling involved.




Just sayin', this answer feels like it's straight out of a GPT somewhere.

@RandalSchwartz, I'll take that as a compliment.
