When passing a widget as a parameter to another widget in Flutter, is there a difference between using `Widget` or `WidgetBuilder`?
class MyWidget {
  final Widget? leading;
  final WidgetBuilder? trailing;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        if(leading != null ) leading,
        AnotherWidget(),
        if(trailing != null) trailing(context),
      ],
    );
}

Are there any pros/cons to using WidgetBuilder instead of Widget for trailing?

This is literally a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78347513/is-there-an-essential-difference-in-using-of-widget-or-widgetbuilder-to-pass which was asked yesterday

Using Widget:
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget? leading;
  final Widget? trailing;

  MyWidget({this.leading, this.trailing});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        if (leading != null) leading!,
        Text('Content'),
        if (trailing != null) trailing!,
      ],
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: MyWidget(
        leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        trailing: Icon(Icons.search),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

In this, trailing directly takes a Widget. It's straightforward and suitable when the widget is already instantiated and ready to use.
Using WidgetBuilder:
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget? leading;
  final WidgetBuilder? trailingBuilder;

  MyWidget({this.leading, this.trailingBuilder});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        if (leading != null) leading!,
        Text('Content'),
        if (trailingBuilder != null) trailingBuilder!(context),
      ],
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: MyWidget(
        leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        trailingBuilder: (context) => IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          onPressed: () {
            // Search action
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

In this trailingBuilder is a WidgetBuilder function. It allows for more dynamic behavior, as the trailing widget can be constructed based on the BuildContext, enabling customization based on context or runtime conditions.
